# Would you guys change the following sentence suitable for my cover letter?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, expressions, american-english, sentence

I need your help guys:) I am applying for an instructor position at a university in the States. Would you please change the following statement appropriate for my cover letter?

"My bachelor's degree in mathematics will also help me significantly to teach your quantitative research method course."

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Hi Hyuk - Proofreading questions are offtopic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use *enable* rather than *help* and discard *significantly*

"My bachelor's degree in mathematics will also enable me to teach your quantitative research method course."

Comment: A degree does **not** *enable* you to teach, unless you mean that having that degree is an official requirement for the teaching *position*. And even in that case it says nothing about whether you can actually teach the course. Being *allowed* to teach is not the same thing as being effectively *able* to teach. A degree also does not *help* you to teach. At most it is a mark that you have the know-how needed for the *content* of the course. Knowing the subject matter to be taught is not the same thing as knowing how to teach it.

Comment: @Drew I agree with your comments completely.  Since this is for a **cover letter,** it should be crafted very carefully.